# Javascript Login form passes Credentials to backend

Tags: javascript, java, authentication, basic-authentication

Im trying to pass authentication headers for sending a JSON to post to a external rest API. I currently have been hardcoding the username and password but I want to be able to allow the user to enter in their credentials and make the post call.

I want help with a basic javascript login form that when the user enter their credentials and presses a button, the credentials are passed to the backend and it takes over and posts the JSON.

```
// ----------- REST SERVICE----------

public class RestService {
    String Username="admin";
    String Password="pass";

  public String createPost() throws AuthenticateException,ClientHandlerException {

String url = "https://someapi.net/rest/api/2/issue/";

Client client = Client.create ();

client.addFilter (new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(Username, Password));
WebResource webResource= client.resource(url);
//--INPUT is formatted a bit different In my app but I just can't show it
String input = "{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}"

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class,input);
string output = response.getEntity(String.Class)
return output;

}
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking how to create a login form with HTML?

Comment: @ChrisG yes that is what im asking essential a login form that any one with a account to use and post the json

Comment: Right, so as far as I can tell, your backend will be posting the JSON, so all you need is a basic `<form>` and three `<input>`s inside. The form/browser will make a POST request to your backend sending along the credentials, and your backend will take over. I'm still not sure what exactly you need help with.

Comment: @ChrisG that is right thank you. I just don't have any experience with creating frontend forms that send inputs to a backend. I've tried searching online but I keep running into more complex ways that Im not familiar with it.

Comment: Here's the minimal setup: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/n2h0zayp/

Comment: @ChrisG how do I reference the values entered in my java code variables username and password ?

Comment: Depends on the backend you're using, that form sends a POST request with the entered values in the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`; any web framework should parse that for you and offer a convenient way to grab the values based on the `name` attribute. In PHP for instance you'd use `$_POST['username']`.